# How to set WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED when config Spring JMS Listener

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using WebSphere MQ and I created a JMS listener by annotation to read incoming messages:

> @JmsListener(destination = "${queues.input}", containerFactory = "listenerFactory")

The incoming messages have a MQMD field called **Accounting Token** set and I would like to read it. From reading IBM doc, I need to set the **WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED** property of the destination to **true**. But the way I configured JmsListener is just a String name in the annotation. How do I set this property?

Comment: I work with IBM MQ but not much with Spring.  I found this post that may be helpful but it is not using a JmsListener. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/97168-how-to-set-wmqconstants-wmq-mqmd-read-enabled-in-spring

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for the link. Yes, I read that one as well.  I just need to get hold of the queue object to set the field.  I just don't know how in Spring. Maybe it is not possible via annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a suitably configured `@Bean` for the destination (`MQQueue` with the required properties set).

Then configure the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` to use a `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` in its `destinationResolver` property.

The resolver should be a `@Bean` too, so it gets a reference to the bean factory.

Then, `${queues.input}` should resolve to the queue's bean name and the listener container will use that destination rather than the default destination resolver, which creates a destination from the `Session`.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify...

The `destination` property of the annotation is actually a destination name that gets resolved to a `Destination` object using the configured `DestinationResolver`.

The default resolver (`DynamicDestinationResolver`) simply calls `session.createQueue()` or `session.createTopic()` - so you get whatever default destination the JMS provider's client library gives you.

With the `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` we resolve the destination name to a bean in the application context, which can be a fully configured destination object, tailored to your provider's library.

So, you simply configure the DMLC to use the BF resolver, either directly (as you tried) or via the container factory - which is used to create a DMLC for each `@JmsListener` found and passes the resolver into each. So the destination name is resolved to a fully configured `Destination` instance.

Comment: thanks.  It works!  I also got it working by configuring DefaultJmsListenerContainer instead of JmsListenerContainerFactory. But I like your solution better.   Do you mind giving a more detailed explanation about what happens behind the scene?

Comment: I edited the answer with some clarification; hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I will upvote and accept your answer later (those functions don't work at work for some reason).